# How to check the end of the frame in modbus RTU

Tags: c#, visual-studio, modbus

I have this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort();

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.PortName = "COM11";
        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        byte[] data_in = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
        sp.Read(data_in, 0, data_in.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(data_in[0]);
    }
```

I send frame in simulator "0A030000002184A9 "and receive it in my program.

How do i check that is it the end of the frame? Because sometimes frame is not full.

Answer (score 1):

If you were abiding strictly by the spec, the framing would be determined by measuring gaps of silence on the serial line.

You can't do this on a PC.

Instead you need to keep track of some state per-response - once you've read at least the function code you can determine how many bytes are in the rest of the response, plus 2 more bytes for the CRC.

Answer (score 1):

if talking about modbus
Receiving data lenght is expected data and defined your response or you can solve 3rd byte of messege for the master.

otherwise this for slave, 3.5 chartime wait to end frame.